# Adding condition to data-bind="with"

Tags: knockout.js

I have a Users table, each user is clickable, once you click on it- a modal popups with the user's information.

the `div` of the modal:

```
<div class="infoForm" data-bind="with: $root.selectedItem">
      <input id="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" data-bind="value: name" />
      <div class="cont">
      <label for="address">ADDRESS</label>
      <input class="contField" placeholder="Address 1" id="address" data-bind="value: address1" />
      <input class="contField" placeholder="Address 2" id="address2" data-bind="value: address2" />
      <input class="contField" id="city" placeholder="City" data-bind="value: city" />
      <input class="contField" id="state" placeholder="State" data-bind="value: state" />
      <input class="contField" id="zip" placeholder="Zip" data-bind="value: zip" />
...
</div>
```

The problem is that if `selectedItem` is empty, the modal popups blank, without any content.

I wanted to add a condition to the `data-bind` to happen only if `$root.selectedItem` is not `null` becasue when I take out the `data-bind` at all it does work.

I tried that:

```
<div class="infoForm" data-bind="with: $root.selectedItem ? $root.selectedItem : ''">
    .....
</div>
```

But it doesn't work, it just doesn't happen, in other types of binding (`text`, `value` it does work).

The `selectedItem` is being set when one of the users on the table is being clicked:

```
 <td class="name n" data-bind="text: name, click: $root.setSelectedItems.bind($data)"></td>
```

The View Model:

```
var UsersViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    ...

    self.setSelectedItems = function (selectedUser) {
    if (selectedUser) {
        self.selectedItem(selectedUser);
    }
}
}
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: If `selectedItem` equals `null`, the `infoForm`'s inner elements shouldn't be rendered nor data-bound... Also note that if you're putting `if`/`else` logic in your data-binds and use observables, you'll have to call them: `$root.selectedItem() ? /* ... */ : /* ... */`

Comment: @user3297291 Thank you, this div is a modal that popups on button click, the first time the modal is being opened, when `selectedItem` is `null` the modal comes up empty, when I take out `data-bind="with: $root.selectedItem` it opens with the content.

Comment: You might have to show more of the DOM/viewmodel structure for us to help... It's worth pointing out that the actual `infoForm` element will *always* render. The `with` binding only adds/removes its inner contents. Are you sure you're correctly setting/clearing `selectedItem`?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the modal in `<!-- ko if: selectedItem --><div data-bind="with: selectedItem"></div><!-- / ko -->` It's a bit ugly but probably works...

Comment: @user3297291 I tried, same result.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by setting the `selectedItem` with an empty `user`:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable(new User(""));
```